# Why a tcache bin is associated with an arena?

Tags: c, multithreading, heap-memory, glibc

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with `glibc-2.27`, a distribution where the `tcache` re-allocation system is deployed. While debugging some image with `gdb` + `gef` (aka [GDB Enhanced Features](https://github.com/hugsy/gef)) I have noticed that the `tcache` bin is associated with an arena.

A generic `heap bins` command output look like this:

```
gef➤  heap bins
───────────── Tcachebins for arena 0x7ffff7dcfc40 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Tcachebins[idx=0, size=0x10] count=1  ←  Chunk(addr=0x555555756260, size=0x20, flags=PREV_INUSE)
```

As one can tell from the output, the `tcache` bins are associated with an arena. This looks odd to me, since the whole idea of `tcache` (at least the way I got it) was to avoid the race between threads which was caused by locking arenas.

I did some research of [Malloc Internals](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals) at glibc wiki, and I found what I already knew:

> Each thread has a per-thread cache (called the tcache) containing a small collection of chunks which can be accessed without needing to lock an arena.

So, what is the relationship between arenas and `tcache` bins? if I can access the `tcache` without locking an arena why `gef` print an arena (address)? Thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a presentation issue in the GDB plugin. Instances of the tcache are associated with threads, not arenas.  One tcache instance can contain allocations from multiple different arenas, not just the arena currently associated with the thread to which the tcache belongs.

Comment: Wow I actually never thought about one `tcache` having chunks from multiple arenas but yes, it does make sense. Thanks!